# how can i set RadioGroup unchecked by default in android?

Tags: android, radio-group

I am doing an app to conduct simple quiz.I have given the answers are multiple choice using [`RadioGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html). So on loading each question how can I set [`RadioGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) unchecked by default ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just set the `checked` Property in your XML for every `RadioButton` to false:

```
android:checked="false"
```

That should solve the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked on the android developer guide?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html

> Intially, all of the radio buttons are unchecked.

Although you can do this in code with the [`clearCheck()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#clearCheck%28%29) method

> Clears the selection. When the selection is cleared, no radio button in this group is selected and getCheckedRadioButtonId() returns null.

Perhaps your problem might be a different from my understanding. Perhaps explain more about how you are loading questions and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
RadioGroup.check(0)
```

0 is an id which will nevere be generated by adt

upd: from source of RadioGroup

```
public class RadioGroup extends LinearLayout {
    // holds the checked id; the selection is empty by default
    private int mCheckedId = -1;
    ...
```